# The delay between motor BEMF and Hall effect sensor output

Tags: motor, brushless-dc-motor, hall-effect

I have a BLDC motor with Hall effect sensor feedback. The Hall sensors are located in the center of every tooth of the motor *(Figure 1)* based on mechanical and electrical degree calculation.

[image: Figure 1 Hall sensor placement example]

I have looked over related BEMF signal vs the Hall sensor output. There is no drive section, only spun the motor by hand, not too fast.

As far as I know, for example, if you look at BEMFUV (U+,V-), you should see the switch from low to high or high to low in every zero crossing point.

As you see, thoughthere is a significant delay between the Hall output and the BEMF zero crossing point. The periods of the Hall signals are the same. In every BEMF signal waveform, the same situation exists. *(Figure 2)*

**Note:** HALLU=Green, HALLV=Yellow, HALLW=Blue.

[image: Figure 2 BEMFUV vs HALLV Signal Waveform]

There is no offset in the Hall sensor placement for each 3 steps tooth of motor, centered placed.

What is the explanation for the delay between the Hall sensor output and the BEMF zero crossing point? How can I prevent this?

If the Hall sensors are not properly aligned we can use a delay function on microcontroller side. Is the delay normal or not?

Comment: Are you sure it is delayed?  Or could yellow be slightly *ahead*?  Compare sine to yellow across a wide speed range to see if it "falls into line" once the speed is increased.

Comment: Where are the Hall sensors positioned radially? If there is an angular offset, you will see a delay. If you vary the RPM, is it  a fixed time or fixed angle?

Comment: If you actually powered the motor to run as a motor, would there be a natural phase shift in the BEMF signal?

Comment: @rdtsc, i can not spin the motor fast by hand. I should connect it against a different motor/load.

Comment: @andyaka The motor is not powered, the phase cables were lefted.

Comment: Sorry, insufficient machine knowledge on my part. I had to choose between that and electronics in school. Can you spin it at two different RPM, what result do you get?

Comment: @winny, i have tried less RPM than the oscillagram you see, but same delay/ahead or something else exists.

Comment: I don’t suppose the phase shift is 30 deg, the amount yould get from delta to wye?

Comment: What I mean is that if you powered it, the phase angle may align.

Comment: @Bryan, the motor is star(Y) connected.

Comment: Measure the delay between magenta and blue with the scope in addition to the period.  Repeat with the motor turning at different speeds and in both directions.  The numbers may provide some clue.

Comment: @Andyaka, I will try it. But, why it may be aligned when it powered?

Comment: Because rotor current creates a magnetic field. Look up "inter-poles" used on DC motors with commutation; they manipulate the local mag field around the brushes to stop them sparking and, who is to say that something similar may not be happening here.

Comment: @pj-yn9aq, i tried for different speeds and looked at BEMFUV, BEMFVW, BEMFWU and related hall signals; it is all same.

Comment: What is all same?  The delayed time or the delayed time divided by the period?

Comment: @Andyaka , I have powered the phases and tested again, but the delay is same. There is no change the time between the Hall output and BEMF zero crossing point; hall signal started to go low to high before zero crossing point.

Comment: @pj-yn9aq , I mean there is no change the time between the Hall output and BEMF zero crossing point.

Comment: That is weird.  The delay between magenta and blue should be around ¼ or ¾ of the period depending on which direction the motor turns.  So it should change when the speed changes.  How did you pick the speed for the oscilloscope screenshot, did you pick this speed because there is a nice phase shift between magenta and blue around 90° only at this speed?  What happens if you turn the motor twice or 4 times as fast at about 250 rpm or 500 rpm (try both directions), do the hall effect signals stay constant?

Comment: @pj-yn9aq , of course the periods of Hall sensors change. But, the delay continues. In another direction, low Hall outputs go to high, high Hall outputs go to low.

Comment: The same problem is existed.